# Why I can't find a value for the resistivity of plastic?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, material-science

I'm working to a relation about resistence of various materials. I haven't found a table of resistivity wich includes Plastic. Is searching plastic too general? Does a table in which there is at least a range  exist?

Comment: Here is the first link when you google [resistivity plastics](https://omnexus.specialchem.com/polymer-properties/properties/volume-resistivity) which includes a list of the resistivity of many plastics and a useful note about surface resistivity and volume resistivity.

Comment: When asking a question about where to find information you should tell us where you have already looked, especially web searches you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dmckee is correct, plastic isn't descriptive of a single material, but rather a class of the more general term, polymeric material.

UL LLC (formerly Underwriters Laboratories Inc.), an independent testing laboratory, publishes data for a number of properties of literally thousands of polymeric materials as part of its component recognition program. One of the properties is "volume resistivity". Many manufacturers of polymeric materials have UL recognized plastics. The data is primarily used by manufacturers of end products using the material. As @Dmckee pointed out, generally this is not information given to consumers, but rather to prospective purchasers of the plastic for end product applications. But I suppose it can't hurt to ask.

In any case, I believe you will find that the volume resistivity of most plastics is within a fairly narrow range. Check out the following link:

https://omnexus.specialchem.com/polymer-properties/properties/volume-resistivity

The exceptions are materials with fillers that increase electrical conductivity, like carbon fibers. For example in the link you will see that the volume resistivity for LCP Carbon Fiber-reinforced, is significantly lower than most. Some plastics used as housings for electronic equipment are impregnated with conductive fillers such as carbon fiber for the purpose of suppressing electromagnetic interference with other equipment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

"Plastic" isn't descriptive of *a* material. That word represents a large class of materials whose physical properties vary enormously.

Look up the *kind* of plastic you care about.

But be aware that when you look up "acrylic" (to take one possible) example you will almost certainly find answers given as a range. Because "acrylic" is still representative of a still fairly-large and varied class of materials.

The place to find reasonable precise value is on the manufacturers data sheet for the particular material that you are looking at. Alas, for consumer products you don't generally have that. The manufacturer of the *product* (as opposed to the manufacturer of the plastic stock material) has it, but they don't generally pass it along to the consumer.